# Regular Expression to match against first character and file extension

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I'm using Bash to try to write a command that gets every file where the first character is not 'a' and the file does not end with '.html' but cannot seem to get both to work properly.

So far I can get my regex to match all the files that start with 'a' and end with '.html' and remove them but my issue that I cannot seem to solve is when the file starts with 'a' and ends with a different file extension. My regex seems to ignore that second requirement and just hides it regardless.

```
cat inputfile.txt | sed -n '/^[^a].*[^html$]/p'
```

Input File Contents:

```
123
anapple.html
456
theapple.html
789
nottrue.html
apple.csv 
12
```

Output:

```
123
456
theapple.html
789
nottrue.html
12
```

Comment: You need to review a regexp tutorial to find out what `[^html$]` means. It's a single character that's not `h`, `t`, `m`, `l`, or `$`.

Comment: also the `$` shouldn't be inside the `[]` if you meant the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to write a pattern that matches the rows to keep, write a pattern that matches the rows to remove, and use `grep -v` to print all the lines that don't match it.

```
grep -v '^a.*\.html$' inputfile.txt
```